# Putting together several ListPlot 2D in a 3D graphic

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

I'm trying to put together several different 2D plots in a 3D graphics to create a figure which would be like the one below (taken from https://aip.scitation.org/doi/10.1063/1.4998724)[image]

However my plots are not contour plot like on this example. My plots looks like the one below where I used ListPlot to draw the different curves.

[image: ![enter image description here]

I tried with ListPlot3D and ListPointPlot3D but with these two functions I didn't succeed to join the points to form the different curves like on the figure above and without joining them between two different plots.

Edit:

Here are the data that I used to plot the example:

`{{{70,-3.28540334263527},{71,-3.27432278919873},{72,-3.26369368174397},{73,-3.25350695026436},{74,-3.24375348226142},{75,-3.23442415473233},{76,-3.22550986251597},{77,-3.21700154312006},{78,-3.20889019829817},{79,-3.20116691256438},{80,-3.19382286878205},{81,-3.18684936107068},{82,-3.18023780506416},{83,-3.17397974576673},{84,-3.16806686299172},{85,-3.16249097460629},{86,-3.15724403754810},{87,-3.15231814685867},{88,-3.14770553296841},{89,-3.14339855987631},{90,-3.13937707615996},{91,-3.14339855977977},{92,-3.14770553286154},{93,-3.15231814673735},{94,-3.15724403741609},{95,-3.16249097446346},{96,-3.16806686283783},{97,-3.17397974559794},{98,-3.18023780488394},{99,-3.18684936087512},{100,-3.19382286857901},{101,-3.20116691234546},{102,-3.20889019806751},{103,-3.21700154287390},{104,-3.22550986225745},{105,-3.23442415445781},{106,-3.24375348197424},{107,-3.25350694996440},{108,-3.26369368142447},{109,-3.27432278886608},{110,-3.28540334228624}},{{70,-3.11063325021876},{71,-3.11022689504167},{72,-3.10996312550354},{73,-3.10985209796379},{74,-3.10990342145198},{75,-3.11012622440815},{76,-3.11052921650446},{77,-3.11112074579084},{78,-3.11190885158078},{79,-3.11290131322705},{80,-3.11410569523733},{81,-3.11552938883352},{82,-3.11717965019974},{83,-3.11906363569176},{84,-3.12118843406927},{85,-3.12356109603436},{86,-3.12618866107205},{87,-3.12907818179438},{88,-3.13223674550530},{89,-3.13567149057300},{90,Indeterminate},{91,-3.13567149064917},{92,-3.13223674557155},{93,-3.12907818184708},{94,-3.12618866109730},{95,-3.12356109606813},{96,-3.12118843409384},{97,-3.11906363570343},{98,-3.11717965020261},{99,-3.11552938882398},{100,-3.11410569522326},{101,-3.11290131320091},{102,-3.11190885154672},{103,-3.11112074575196},{104,-3.11052921645137},{105,-3.11012622434405},{106,-3.10990342138101},{107,-3.10985209788629},{108,-3.10996312541193},{109,-3.11022689494425},{110,-3.11063325011183}},{{70,-3.09890860461704},{71,-3.09812297332464},{72,-3.09746808563295},{73,-3.09695377137550},{74,-3.09658930768585},{75,-3.09638348624581},{76,-3.09634467572243},{77,-3.09648087964960},{78,-3.09679979012982},{79,-3.09730883765275},{80,-3.09801523725152},{81,-3.09892603134186},{82,-3.10004812935466},{83,-3.10138834448757},{84,-3.10295342763722},{85,-3.10475009880658},{86,-3.10678507600178},{87,-3.10906510187972},{88,-3.11159696815476},{89,-3.11438753791437},{90,-3.11744376588204},{91,-3.11438753797592},{92,-3.11159696820685},{93,-3.10906510191859},{94,-3.10678507603137},{95,-3.10475009882735},{96,-3.10295342764910},{97,-3.10138834448689},{98,-3.10004812934564},{99,-3.09892603132066},{100,-3.09801523722618},{101,-3.09730883761564},{102,-3.09679979008510},{103,-3.09648087959366},{104,-3.09634467565940},{105,-3.09638348617204},{106,-3.09658930760547},{107,-3.09695377128884},{108,-3.09746808553250},{109,-3.09812297321862},{110,-3.09890860450176}}}`

Does anyone know how to do this?

Thank you in advance for your response.

---

Thank you everyone for all the answers!
I'll try each of your method and see which one fits better for my plots.

Comment: Please provide sample data for a minimal example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
lp = ListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> ColorData[97] /@ {4, 1, 2}, 
  Frame -> True]
```

[image]

We can define a function that transforms the graphics primitives of `lp` to the desired 3D primitives and use these primitives with `Graphics3D`:

```
ClearAll[translations]
translations[levels : {__} : {1}, dir : "X" | "Y" | "Z" : "X", h_: (0 &)] := 
  ReplaceAll[Point[x_] :> Module[{d = dir /. Thread[{"X", "Y", "Z"} -> Range[3]]}, 
   {Point @ #, Line @ #} & /@ Table[Insert[#, i + h @@ #, d] & /@ x, {i, levels}]]];
```

***Examples:***

Make 3 copies placed at `x = 1`, `x = 2` and `x = 3`:

```
Graphics3D[translations[Range[3]] @ lp[[1]], 
  BoxRatios -> {2, 1, 1}, ImageSize -> Large, Axes -> True]
```

[image]

Make 3 copies at `y = 1`, `y = 2` and `y = 3`:

```
Graphics3D[translations[Range[3], "Y"] @ lp[[1]], 
 BoxRatios -> {1, 2, 1}, ImageSize -> Large, Axes -> True]
```

[image]

Make 3 copies at `z = 1`, `z = 2` and `z = 3`:

```
Graphics3D[translations[Range[3], "Z"] @ lp[[1]], 
 BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 2}, ImageSize -> Large, Axes -> True]
```

[image]

5 copies at random x positions between 1 and 100:

```
SeedRandom[1]
Graphics3D[translations[RandomSample[Range[100], 5]]@lp[[1]], 
 BoxRatios -> {2, 1, 1}, ImageSize -> Large, Axes -> True]
```

[image]

Perturb x-coordinates by `Sin[y Pi /40 + z 100 Pi/3]/10`:

```
Graphics3D[{translations[Range[3], "X", .1 Sin[# Pi /40 + #2 100 Pi/3] &] @ lp[[1]], 
  Text[Style["☺", 46], {#, 90, -3.10}] & /@ {1, 2, 3}},
  BoxRatios -> {2, 1, 1}, ImageSize -> Large, Axes -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer! This is really helpful!

Answer (score 5):

You could duplicate the points with values assigned on a third axis. For example using row values `{1,2,3,4,5,6}`:

```
rows = Range[6];
data2 = Table[PadLeft[lst, {Length[lst], 3}, r], {r, rows}, {lst, data}];
ListPointPlot3D[Flatten[data2, 1], PlotStyle -> {Red, Lighter@Blue, Orange}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

```
data = {{{70, -3.28540334263527}, {71, -3.27432278919873}, {72, \
-3.26369368174397}, {73, -3.25350695026436}, {74, -3.24375348226142}, \
{75, -3.23442415473233}, {76, -3.22550986251597}, {77, \
-3.21700154312006}, {78, -3.20889019829817}, {79, -3.20116691256438}, \
{80, -3.19382286878205}, {81, -3.18684936107068}, {82, \
-3.18023780506416}, {83, -3.17397974576673}, {84, -3.16806686299172}, \
{85, -3.16249097460629}, {86, -3.15724403754810}, {87, \
-3.15231814685867}, {88, -3.14770553296841}, {89, -3.14339855987631}, \
{90, -3.13937707615996}, {91, -3.14339855977977}, {92, \
-3.14770553286154}, {93, -3.15231814673735}, {94, -3.15724403741609}, \
{95, -3.16249097446346}, {96, -3.16806686283783}, {97, \
-3.17397974559794}, {98, -3.18023780488394}, {99, -3.18684936087512}, \
{100, -3.19382286857901}, {101, -3.20116691234546}, {102, \
-3.20889019806751}, {103, -3.21700154287390}, {104, \
-3.22550986225745}, {105, -3.23442415445781}, {106, \
-3.24375348197424}, {107, -3.25350694996440}, {108, \
-3.26369368142447}, {109, -3.27432278886608}, {110, \
-3.28540334228624}}, {{70, -3.11063325021876}, {71, \
-3.11022689504167}, {72, -3.10996312550354}, {73, -3.10985209796379}, \
{74, -3.10990342145198}, {75, -3.11012622440815}, {76, \
-3.11052921650446}, {77, -3.11112074579084}, {78, -3.11190885158078}, \
{79, -3.11290131322705}, {80, -3.11410569523733}, {81, \
-3.11552938883352}, {82, -3.11717965019974}, {83, -3.11906363569176}, \
{84, -3.12118843406927}, {85, -3.12356109603436}, {86, \
-3.12618866107205}, {87, -3.12907818179438}, {88, -3.13223674550530}, \
{89, -3.13567149057300}, {90, 
     Indeterminate}, {91, -3.13567149064917}, {92, \
-3.13223674557155}, {93, -3.12907818184708}, {94, -3.12618866109730}, \
{95, -3.12356109606813}, {96, -3.12118843409384}, {97, \
-3.11906363570343}, {98, -3.11717965020261}, {99, -3.11552938882398}, \
{100, -3.11410569522326}, {101, -3.11290131320091}, {102, \
-3.11190885154672}, {103, -3.11112074575196}, {104, \
-3.11052921645137}, {105, -3.11012622434405}, {106, \
-3.10990342138101}, {107, -3.10985209788629}, {108, \
-3.10996312541193}, {109, -3.11022689494425}, {110, \
-3.11063325011183}}, {{70, -3.09890860461704}, {71, \
-3.09812297332464}, {72, -3.09746808563295}, {73, -3.09695377137550}, \
{74, -3.09658930768585}, {75, -3.09638348624581}, {76, \
-3.09634467572243}, {77, -3.09648087964960}, {78, -3.09679979012982}, \
{79, -3.09730883765275}, {80, -3.09801523725152}, {81, \
-3.09892603134186}, {82, -3.10004812935466}, {83, -3.10138834448757}, \
{84, -3.10295342763722}, {85, -3.10475009880658}, {86, \
-3.10678507600178}, {87, -3.10906510187972}, {88, -3.11159696815476}, \
{89, -3.11438753791437}, {90, -3.11744376588204}, {91, \
-3.11438753797592}, {92, -3.11159696820685}, {93, -3.10906510191859}, \
{94, -3.10678507603137}, {95, -3.10475009882735}, {96, \
-3.10295342764910}, {97, -3.10138834448689}, {98, -3.10004812934564}, \
{99, -3.09892603132066}, {100, -3.09801523722618}, {101, \
-3.09730883761564}, {102, -3.09679979008510}, {103, \
-3.09648087959366}, {104, -3.09634467565940}, {105, \
-3.09638348617204}, {106, -3.09658930760547}, {107, \
-3.09695377128884}, {108, -3.09746808553250}, {109, \
-3.09812297321862}, {110, -3.09890860450176}}};
```

Convert your data to 3D

```
data3D = MapIndexed[Insert[#1, First@#2, 2] &, 
   data /. {_, Indeterminate} :> Nothing, {2}];

Show[
 ListPointPlot3D[data3D],
 Graphics3D[Line /@ data3D],
 PlotRange -> Full,
 BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Manually crafting the 3d data is a good approach and may be acceptable.  Another approach is to use the `ListLinePlot`s themselves as textures for 3d polygons:

```
dat=yourlist&/@Range@6;
Show@@Join[
  {Plot3D[0,{x,1,6},{y,0,1},
  PlotRange->{{1,6},{0,1},{0,1}},RegionFunction->False,
  Ticks->Automatic,Lighting->{{"Ambient",White}},FaceGrids->All]},
  
  Graphics3D[{EdgeForm@None,Texture@Image@
    ListLinePlot[dat[[#]],PlotMarkers->
    {"\[FilledCircle]", "\[FilledSquare]","\[FilledDiamond]"},
    PlotStyle->{Red,Blue,Orange},Ticks->None],
    Polygon[{{#,0,0},{#,1,0},{#,1,1},{#,0,1}},
    VertexTextureCoordinates->{{0,0},{1,0},{1,1},{0,1}}]}]&/@
  Range@6,{BoxRatios->Automatic}]
```

The first `Plot3D` is a dummy plot (`RegionFunction->False`; it plots nothing) to get customizable `FaceGrid`s, `Ticks`, `Label`s etc.  `Lighting` is important because the default lighting looks weird on the images of the plots.  A big drawback is the plots aren't transparent, though I think this can be achieved.  Perhaps this approach is useful if your plots are hard to reproduce by hand with simple 3d lines or have complicated styles.

[image: plot]