# how can I put axes with different values on the same graph

Tags: graphics, graphics3d

[image: the format I want]
[image: result]

**My difficulty is to find a way to make the other waves are aligned with different axes and parts with different times**

````
    'Manipulate[
     wave1 = ParametricPlot3D[{{0, u, Sech[u]}}, {u, -10, 10}, 
       PlotStyle -> Directive[Thickness[.007], Lighter[Black, .5]]];
     wave2 = ParametricPlot3D[{{t, u, Sech[u - t]}}, {u, -10, 10}, 
       PlotStyle -> Directive[Thickness[.007], Lighter[Black, .5]]];
     wave3 = ParametricPlot3D[{{t*2, u, Sech[u - t*2]}}, {u, -10, 10}, 
       PlotStyle -> Directive[Thickness[.007], Lighter[Black, .5]]];
     Show[
      wave1, Graphics3D[{Opacity[1], 
        EdgeForm[], (wave1[[1]] /. 
          Line[t___] :> Polygon[Append[t, {Last[t][[1]], 0, 0}]])}],
      wave2, Graphics3D[{Opacity[1], 
        EdgeForm[], (wave2[[1]] /. 
          Line[t___] :> Polygon[Append[t, {Last[t][[1]], 0, 0}]])}],
      wave3, Graphics3D[{Opacity[1], 
        EdgeForm[], (wave3[[1]] /. 
          Line[t___] :> Polygon[Append[t, {Last[t][[1]], 0, 0}]])}],
      Boxed -> False, SphericalRegion -> False, 
      PlotRange -> {{-3, 10}, {-3, 3}, {-1, 2}}, Axes -> True, 
      Ticks -> False, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}, 
      AxesLabel -> {Style["t", Italic], Style["x", Italic], 
        Style["y", Italic]}, ImageSize -> {400, 400}, 
      AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[{{Automatic, Automatic, h}}],
      ImageSize -> {400, 400}], {{t, 0.311, "t"}, 0, 10}]```
````

Comment: Related [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/243823/putting-together-several-listplot-2d-in-a-3d-graphic)

Comment: `SliceContourPlot3D` with surface specification `{"YStackedPlanes", 3}` might work.  In any case, do not clutter your code with `Manipulate` and formatting options until your basic code is working.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

`ImagePadding` was used to shift each plot up and over by some amount and then `Show` was used to display the shifted plots on top of each other.  The code that produced the image is

```
Clear[plot] 
plot[k_] := With[{kmax = 3, pad = 30},
  Image@Plot[5 + (x - k) (1 - x + k), {x, -2 + k, 3 + k},
    Axes -> If[k == 0, True, {True, False}],
    AxesOrigin -> {0, 0},
    Filling -> Axis,
    FillingStyle -> GrayLevel[1 - .2 k/kmax, .9],
    Frame -> False,
    GridLines -> None,
    ImagePadding -> {{20 + k*pad, 20 + (kmax - k)*pad}, {20 + k*pad, 
       20 + (kmax - k)*pad}},
    PlotRange -> {{-3, 10}, {0, 9}}]
  ]
arr = Graphics[Arrow[{{160, 45}, {580, 465}}],
   ImageSize -> ImageDimensions[plot[0]]];

Show[{arr, plot[3], plot[2], plot[1], plot[0]},
  ImageSize -> Medium] // ImageCrop
```

Each plot is padded on all sides by a minimum of 20 to allow room the scales.  The first plot is padded on the right and above by an additional `kmax*pad`.  The each successive plot is padded more on the left and the bottom and less on the right and the top.  Note that the `GrayLevel` directive includes an opacity parameter, which is set to 0.9.

The above code includes an arrow that does not appear the above graphics.