# Putting together several photos in a 3D graphic

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

I need to put several images in 3D, like here: [Putting together several ListPlot 2D in a 3D graphic](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/243823/putting-together-several-listplot-2d-in-a-3d-graphic) except that I want to place several photos in space. Sample images are attached. Thank you for your reply.
[image][enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FiGyu.jpg)[image]

Answer (score 3):

You may use "Texture" to bring 2D images in a 3D space.

Here is an example. To preserve the scales you will have to adjust the size of the polygons:

```
Graphics3D[{Texture[im1], 
  Polygon[{{-1, -1, 2}, {1, -1, 2}, {1, 1, 2}, {-1, 1, 2}}, 
   VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}],
  Texture[im2], 
  Polygon[{{-1, -1, 1}, {1, -1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}, {-1, 1, 1}}, 
   VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}]
  }, Lighting -> "Neutral"]
```

[image]