# Creating a 3D Plot with Colored Lines from 2D Data Sets with Color Labels

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, color, legending

I got the following table of my data:[Amplitudes at each site for different t1-values and energy eigenvalues](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IkKTa.jpg)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IkKTa.jpg)

and I am trying to plot the amplitudes at each site for every t1-value such that a 3Dplot is created in terms of {x=numberofsite,y=t1-value,z={amplituevalue1,amplituevalue2,amplituevalue3,amplituevalue4}} having therefore a line when linking all the amplitudevalues. Nevertheless, I want each line to be colored according to its energy value. Can someone help me do this?
For now, what I have achieved is to make the two dplots and stack them together using insets inside a Graphics 3D, but the y-axis with each t1 value is missing, and it does not work very well.

Here is an example of this method with only the two first t1-values {-3,-2}:

```
     (*Amplitudes at each site and respective eigenvalues*)
    eigenvectors = {{{0.20275444087384661`, 0.29724555912615347`, 
         0.29724555912615347`, 
         0.20275444087384661`}, {0.20275444087384661`, 
         0.29724555912615347`, 0.29724555912615347`, 
         0.20275444087384661`}, {0.2972455591261534`, 
         0.20275444087384664`, 0.20275444087384664`, 
         0.29724555912615336`}, {0.2972455591261534`, 
         0.20275444087384664`, 0.20275444087384664`, 
         0.29724555912615336`}}, {{0.16161165235168157`, 
         0.3383883476483185`, 0.3383883476483185`, 
         0.16161165235168157`}, {0.16161165235168157`, 
         0.3383883476483185`, 0.3383883476483185`, 
         0.16161165235168157`}, {0.33838834764831843`, 
         0.16161165235168157`, 0.16161165235168157`, 
         0.33838834764831843`}, {0.33838834764831843`, 
         0.16161165235168157`, 0.16161165235168157`, 
         0.33838834764831843`}}};
    eigenvalues = {{-3.1457513110645907`, 
        3.1457513110645907`, -2.1457513110645907`, 
        2.1457513110645907`}, {-1.9142135623730951`, 
        1.9142135623730951`, -0.9142135623730951`, 0.9142135623730951`}};
    
    amplitudes[i_] := Transpose[eigenvectors[[i]]];
    
    (*Colouring the amplitudes according to respective eigenvalues*)
    colors[i_] := ColorData["Rainbow"] /@ Rescale[eigenvalues[[i]]];
    
    (*2D Plots of the amplitudes with colored lines according to eigenvalues*)
    plot2d = Table[
      ListLinePlot[Transpose@amplitudes[i], PlotStyle -> colors[i], 
       Frame -> True, 
       PlotLegends -> BarLegend[{"Rainbow", MinMax[eigenvalues]}, LegendLabel -> "Eigenvalues"]], {i, 1, 2}]
```

[image: 2Dplots]

```
    (*3DPlot considering the previous 2dplots stacked together and with the respective coloured lines*)
    Show[Graphics3D[{Inset[plot2d[[1]], {0, 0, 0}], 
       Inset[plot2d[[2]], {0, 0, 1}]}, Boxed -> False, 
      ViewPoint -> {2, -2, 2}], PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {0, 1}}, 
[PlotLabel: "Combined 3D Plot"]
```

[image: 3DPlot]

I tried this method [4](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/243823/putting-together-several-listplot-2d-in-a-3d-graphic), but it won't work.
I also tried reorganizing the original data through {x,y,z}, but the most I could do was the following:

```
    xyzQData = {{{{-3, 1, 0.202754, -3.14575}, {-3, 1, 
      0.202754, -3.14575}, {-3, 1, 0.297246, -3.14575}, {-3, 1, 
      0.297246, -3.14575}}, {{-3, 2, 0.297246, 3.14575}, {-3, 2, 
      0.297246, 3.14575}, {-3, 2, 0.202754, 3.14575}, {-3, 2, 
      0.202754, 3.14575}}, {{-3, 3, 0.297246, -2.14575}, {-3, 3, 
      0.297246, -2.14575}, {-3, 3, 0.202754, -2.14575}, {-3, 3, 
      0.202754, -2.14575}}, {{-3, 4, 0.202754, 2.14575}, {-3, 4, 
      0.202754, 2.14575}, {-3, 4, 0.297246, 2.14575}, {-3, 4, 
      0.297246, 2.14575}}}, {{{-2, 1, 0.161612, -1.91421}, {-2, 1, 
      0.161612, -1.91421}, {-2, 1, 0.338388, -1.91421}, {-2, 1, 
      0.338388, -1.91421}}, {{-2, 2, 0.338388, 1.91421}, {-2, 2, 
      0.338388, 1.91421}, {-2, 2, 0.161612, 1.91421}, {-2, 2, 
      0.161612, 1.91421}}, {{-2, 3, 0.338388, -0.914214}, {-2, 3, 
      0.338388, -0.914214}, {-2, 3, 0.161612, -0.914214}, {-2, 3, 
      0.161612, -0.914214}}, {{-2, 4, 0.161612, 0.914214}, {-2, 4, 
      0.161612, 0.914214}, {-2, 4, 0.338388, 0.914214}, {-2, 4, 
      0.338388, 0.914214}}}};

xyzData = xyzQData[[All, All, All, 1; 3]];

zColors = xyzQData[[All, All, All, 4]];

colorFunction[z_, eigenvaluesList_] := 
 ColorData["Rainbow"][Rescale[z, MinMax[eigenvaluesList]]];

plots = Table[
   ListLinePlot3D[Transpose@xyzData[[i]], 
    ColorFunction -> (colorFunction[Flatten[zColors], zColors] &), 
    PlotStyle -> AbsoluteThickness[2], BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, 
    Lighting -> "Neutral", AxesLabel -> {"X", "Y", "Z"}, 
    PlotLegends -> 
     BarLegend[{"Rainbow", MinMax[Flatten[zColors]]}, 
      LegendLabel -> "Eigenvalues"; ViewPoint -> {2.5, 1, 2.5}; {i, 
    Length[xyzData]}];


Show[plots, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: 3DPlot using XYZQvalues]

where the amplitude lines are not correctly colored, like in the 2D plots.